# What's the best practice to store tags of an entity in clickhouse for filtering by them?

Tags: clickhouse

I have only one table 'visits' in clickhouse, engine ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree, the rest is postgree. Each visit can have multiple tags, like up to 100 tags for one record in maximum.
I need these tags only for filtering data from visits and not going to add tags to select fields.
Obviously now I don't use any joins in my requests at the moment.
The question is: considering performance, which is the best way to implement tags?

I keep in mind two options: relational model, a separate table visit_tags, or json or jsonb without joins.
Maybe there are other options which I haven't find yet? I've considered dictionaries also, but looks like they are for other goals

Comment: Your tags, are they key-value pairs or just strings (like labels)? If they are key-value pairs, what types of values can be represented?

Comment: Just strings, but I can consider id (int) => tag (string) key-values

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are no specific tools in ClickHouse for this. I would start with the following separate table:

```sql
create table visit_tags (
    visit_id        UUID,   -- UInt64/String/...
    tag             LowCardinality(String),
    sign            Int8
)
engine = CollapsingMergeTree(sign) -- replicated if needed
primary key (tag, visit_id)
order by (tag, visit_id)
```

or just MergeTree if no tag deletions are needed. This table will allow you to  quickly obtain a subset of visits based on a specific tag:

```sql
select visit_id from visit_tags [final] where tag = 'some_tag'
```

Further optimizations should depend on the workload profile of the database. These could be temporary tables, in-memory tables (like Set or Dictionary), or pre-aggregated materialized views.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is not realtime, **Bitmap** is a good choice. The table DDL of clickhouse is like below:

```sql
create table tag
(
    tag String,
    user_idx AggregateFunction(groupBitmap, UInt8),
    log_date Date)
Engine=MergeTree()
order by tag
partition by toYYYYMMDD(log_date);
```

Then we can insert 4 records:

```sql
insert into tag select 'male' as tag, bitmapBuild([1,3,5,7,9]) as user_idx, today() as log_date;
insert into tag select 'female' as tag, bitmapBuild([2,4,6,8,10]) as user_idx, today() as log_date;  
insert into tag select 'NY' as tag, bitmapBuild([1,3,4,5]) as user_idx, today() as log_date;  
insert into tag select 'iphone' as tag, bitmapBuild([1,3,6,8]) as user_idx, today() as log_date;
```

The result after inserting:

```sql
--- Here I used bitmapToArray function to convert bitmap to array so that we can read the user id in bitmap.
select tag, bitmapToArray(user_idx),log_date from tag format PrettyCompactMonoBlock;


┌─tag────┬─bitmapToArray(user_idx)─┬───log_date─┐
│ iphone │ [1,3,6,8]               │ 2023-11-24 │
│ male   │ [1,3,5,7,9]             │ 2023-11-24 │
│ female │ [2,4,6,8,1]             │ 2023-11-24 │
│ NY     │ [1,3,4,5]               │ 2023-11-24 │
└────────┴─────────────────────────┴────────────┘
```

Now you can do everything you want do with bitmap.
If you want select the users who **live in NY and use iphone**, the query can be like :

```sql
SELECT bitmapToArray(groupBitmapAndState(user_idx)) AS people_in_NY_use_iphone
FROM tag
WHERE tag IN ('iphone', 'NY');


--result 
┌─people_in_NY_use_iphone─┐
│ [1,3]                   │
└─────────────────────────┘
```

Or you may want to get the people who **live in NY or use iphone**.

```sql
SELECT bitmapToArray(groupBitmapOrState(user_idx)) AS people_in_NY_or_use_iphone
FROM tag
WHERE tag IN ('iphone', 'NY');

--result  
┌─people_in_NY_or_use_iphone─┐
│ [1,3,6,8,4,5]              │
└────────────────────────────┘
```

Of course, if your data is real time, you can still implete it with clickhouse materialized view.
The local table can be:

```sql
CREATE TABLE local_table
(
    `id` UInt8,
    `tag` String,
    `log_date` Date
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(log_date)
ORDER BY tag 
--view 

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW tag_view
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree
PARTITION BY log_date
ORDER BY tag AS
SELECT
    tag,
    groupBitmapState(id) AS user_idx
FROM local_table
GROUP BY
    tag,
    log_date
```

Now we insert data and thoes data is as same as example above, but they are not aggregated.

```sql
insert into local_table select 1 as id, 'male' as tag,  today() as log_date;
insert into local_table select 3 as id, 'male' as tag,  today() as log_date;
insert into local_table select 7 as id, 'male' as tag,  today() as log_date;
insert into local_table select 9 as id, 'male' as tag,  today() as log_date;
insert into local_table select 2 as id, 'female' as tag, today() as log_date;  
insert into local_table select 4 as id, 'female' as tag, today() as log_date;  
insert into local_table select 6 as id, 'female' as tag, today() as log_date; 
insert into local_table select 8 as id, 'female' as tag, today() as log_date;  
insert into local_table select 10 as id,'female' as tag, today() as log_date;  
insert into local_table select 1 as id,  'NY' as tag, today() as log_date;  
insert into local_table select 3 as id,  'NY' as tag, today() as log_date;  
insert into local_table select 4 as id,  'NY' as tag, today() as log_date;  
insert into local_table select 5 as id,  'NY' as tag, today() as log_date;  
insert into local_table select  1 as id,'iphone' as tag, today() as log_date;
insert into local_table select  3 as id,'iphone' as tag, today() as log_date;
insert into local_table select  6 as id,'iphone' as tag, today() as log_date;
insert into local_table select  8 as id,'iphone' as tag, today() as log_date;
```

After data inserted, the data in the materialized view is the same as the data in the example above.

```sql
SELECT
    tag,
    bitmapToArray(user_idx)
FROM tag_view
FINAL
FORMAT PrettyCompactMonoBlock;

--- result 
┌─tag────┬─bitmapToArray(user_idx)─┐
│ male   │ [1,3,7,9]               │
│ NY     │ [1,3,4,5]               │
│ female │ [2,4,6,8,10]            │
│ iphone │ [1,3,6,8]               │
└────────┴─────────────────────────┘
```

We can do a lot of complicated logical calculations.And bitmap can save more disk.
But if you want to use it in PRD, you still need to pay attention to a lot of things. Such as the settings of table and the index_granularity , prewhere is very important in this scenario. There can help us to read less bitmap with specified tag.